# How to start application in command line with Maven

Tags: android, maven-2

I want to run Android application in command line after execution `android:deploy maven goal`

Does Maven have some command which can run application after install ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks [mschonaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368544/mschonaker) I found the complete solution for Maven

First you need to add plugin in your POM

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <configuration>
            <executable>${basedir}/scripts/run_app.sh</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

add script in `${basedir}/scripts/` dir with next content:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n your.app.package/.YourMainActivity
```

Command to build and run app

```
mvn clean install android:deploy; mvn exec:exec
```

Comment: Cool. But your solution is incomplete. You're not considering portability, right?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like: http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/plugin-info.html

You can do it with adb instead. But you have to know the Activity name.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n your.app.package/.YourMainActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update. As of version 3.0.0 the android maven plugin has a run goal so you can start a deployed app on all attached devices with

> mvn android:run

It will automatically parse the AndroidManifest and determine which activity to start. To work you have to run the command from within a apk project.

Comment: Dont forget about the -Dandroid.run.debug=true parameter to wait for the debugger to connect.