# How to debug android application built with maven

Tags: java, android, maven, android-intent, maven-2

I'm currently trying to debug android application on my device from eclipse.

Device has been added I can see it both in console and in eclipse. Console (Windows) :

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
0019cca27f2e6e  device
```

And the eclipse :

[image]

I can run the app without any issues on both device/simulator. I just do `clean install` and `android:deploy` followed by `android:run` and works like a charm. But I can't figure out yet how to debug it.

But when I actually run the app on the device(Samsung galaxy SII) I can only see these two processes executing `com.viber.voip` and `com.viber.voip:keepAliveReceiver` I don't see my app even if I run it. However on the simulator/emulator I can see my app running.

I've gone trough this material:

[debugging an app startup with android maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679078/debugging-an-app-startup-with-android-maven-plugin)

[How to start application in command line with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360103/how-to-start-application-in-command-line-with-maven)

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Debug

Can't break the code. Even tried with `maven-exec-plugin` to start debugging by calling the script underneath, here is that plugin in pom :

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>${basedir}/scripts/debug_app.cmd</executable>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The contents of `debug_app.cmd` :

```
adb shell am start -D android.intent.action.MAIN -n my.package.name/.HelloAndroidActivity
```

When I execute this plugin I get the following ERROR :

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=android.intent.action.MAIN }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=android.intent.action.MAIN }
```

Here is my `manifest.xml` if that is needed :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" >
</uses-permission>

<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> -->

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Has anyone manage to debug the device using maven to build the app?

**Question update :**

After adding the `android:debuggable="true"` my app appeared on the devices tab, but I encounter different issue(when I click on the *green debug icon* below).

Please see below :

[image]

I've found this workaround **(solution in addition to the correct answer)** :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9932

And I've accepted answer below. Might come useful as well :

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/DftP5gYcwYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it is ,

1. Enable debug flag in AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Deploy the app on device. You should now see the process id of your application on eclipse debug manager.
3. Now, configure a run/debug configuration of remote java application in eclipse run/config menu.
4. Enter all details of the configuration. The port number will be 3rd column from you image attachment.
5. After starting the application on device "run the remote java application configuration" in eclipse.
6. You application should now hit the breakpoints if any.

Comment: SDK Tools, Revision 8 provided the support for debugging and developers don't have to inclue the attribute android:debuggable in manifest file (U could have a clear understanding at in depth at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986724/can-not-set-debuggable-flag-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

to manifest and turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up